# Node Automatically Scrolls to Comments on Load

Tags: 6, nodes

For some reason, one of my content types scrolls to the comments section of the node every time it loads (instead of starting you at the top of the page). Disabling comments for that node solves the issue, so I know it has to be something to do with the comments. The weird thing is that none of the other content types have this issue - only one. Any ideas??

Edit:
With further testing, hiding the form elements in the comments area seems to solve the issue (setting .box form to display:none). However this is not ideal, as there is no way to post comments then.

Comment: Please check that the installed contributed modules, that might cause this issue.

Comment: does it show that expected behaviour in the url (i.e. www.mysite.com/node/38#comment) or something similar?

Comment: No, it doesn't show that in the URL. And Krishna - It just doesn't make sense that it's only on this 1 content type (same comment settings as the others). It also seems that if I hide the comment 'form' elements via css, the issue disappears.

Comment: It's either: a css transition, a javascript action, or a browser bug/quirk. We can't really help you to debug those from here, we'd need to see the code involved.

Comment: Finally figured this out...although it doesn't make total sense. It ended up coming down to 2 different CCK fields in that content type. I removed both fields and added them back in and it solved the issue. I'm guessing something must have been corrupted somehow along the way.